# MemoryStream readtimeout during generate Excel file

Tags: c#

I created an excel file. It saved correctly on the disk, but now I would like to download it via the browser. I have problem with stream. I have exception:
`ReadTimeout = stream.ReadTimeout` threw an exception of type `System.InvalidOperationException`

My code:

```
...
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet;
    worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(name);

    worksheet.Name = name;

    for (int i = 0; i < nameColumns.Length; i++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = nameColumns[i];
    }
    xlPackage.Save();
}

stream.Position = 0;
var contentType = "application/octet-stream";
var fileName = "fileName.xlsx";
return Ok(File(stream, contentType, fileName));
```

[image: screenshot with error]

Comment: @jazb Unfortunately, I do not understand this. I do not know how to apply it to myself.

Comment: Where do you see this exception occur? Please show a screenshot of where you see it

Comment: @CaiusJard I have added a screen in the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about it; you're seeing that because the debugger calls every property to get its value so it can show you the value on the tooltip, but those properties throw an exception on a MemoryStream because a MemoryStream cannot time out.

MemoryStream has to have those properties because all Streams have them (anything that has Stream as a parent class has these properties), but they don't make sense in the context of a memory stream.

You code doesn't access them when it actually runs so it's fine to ignore them

This is one thing to bear in mind for the future- the debugger accesses *everything* when you ask it to show you an object, which means it probably experience a lot of exceptions that your code never will, unless your code calls the same thing the debugger did (if your code had eg `stream.ReadTineout = 10` it would also get an error)